# File IO with Kotlin multiplatform

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I would like to do some basic filesystem operations on mingwX64 Windows (and possibly other platforms): open, close, read, rename, get metadata, list files in a directory.

I have found one project that promises to implement this functionality: [KotlinxIO](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-io). However, there has been no progress made in years.

Are there any other alternatives or workarounds?

Comment: Note [kolinx-io](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-io) seems to have had some recent development; the latest release, which as of this comment is version 0.3.0, came out September 2023.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the end, I used the library [Korio](https://github.com/korlibs/korge/tree/main/korio). The documentation could be better, but all of the functionality I need is implemented for all platforms (Jvm, Desktop, Android, ..):

```kotlin
import com.soywiz.korio.file.std.*

suspend fun main {
  val cwd = localCurrentDirVfs
  val files = cwd.list()
  cwd["Hello.txt"].open().close()
  cwd["Hello.txt"].renameTo("Hi.txt")
  val metadata = cwd["Hi.txt"].stat()
}
```

On top of that, it allows usage of the same API for accessing online files, zip archives, etc. which is pretty neat.

Answer (score 6):

You might want to look at OKIO. There is *some* multiplatform support, and a Windows target, but I don't know first hand if the filesystem portion is implemented on Windows: https://github.com/square/okio

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the only workaround right now is to use the expect/actual pattern https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mpp-connect-to-apis.html. Then you can use `java.io` for Android, `Bundle` for iOS etc depending on your target platform

Comment: @Alex.T the answer is correct. `java.io` should work on windows too, same as any other library you would use in any other java app(google for it), but this code should only be used inside windows part code(actual), to use it from common you need to create expect/actual methods.

Comment: It does not seem possible to `import java.io` inside `mingwX64Main` out of the box.